# nvim search hidden files also

Tags: neovim

I would like to search into my directories hidden files also.
If I search a file called for example `.gitignore` it can't be opened because I can't see it in my file list.

This is my configuration to open files into my `init.vim`

```
nnoremap <c-p> :Files<cr>
```

How can I search hidden files also?
I don't want a solution like: use `NerdTree` plugin, please.

Comment: `:Files` is an fzf command. So you don't want a plugin solution but your problem is caused by a plugin? Have a look at the plugins [github page](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#respecting-gitignore-hgignore-and-svnignore)

Comment: I would like to use fzf plugin but searching hidden files also, is it possible @DoktorOSwaldo?

Comment: you can do whatever you want in your `$FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND`

Comment: ok but I don't know how to see hidden files so :) @DoktorOSwaldo

Comment: again, have a look at the fzf [github page](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#respecting-gitignore-hgignore-and-svnignore) This question can not be answered generally since we don't know what search engine you are using in FZF. Also hidden files are not the same like gitignored files.